# How can I display unique words contained in a Bash string?

Tags: linux, string, bash, duplicates

I have a string that has duplicate words. I would like to display only the unique words. The string is:

```
variable="alpha bravo charlie alpha delta echo charlie"
```

I know several tools that can do this together. This is what I figured out:

```
echo $variable | tr " " "\n" | sort -u | tr "\n" " "
```

What is a more effective way to do this?

Comment: Nope, that looks like the normal way to do it.

Comment: You should clarify whether you want the output to be _sorted_ unique words (as in your own solution attempt), or unique words _in input order_.

Comment: I've edited your question lightly to remove the request for tools, which was likely to gather close votes. As edited, I think it's a reasonable question that many inexperienced shell users would struggle with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Use a Bash Substitution Expansion

The following [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) will substitute spaces with newlines, and then pass the results into the *sort* utility to return only the unique words.

```
$ echo -e "${variable// /\\n}" | sort -u
alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
echo
```

This has the side-effect of sorting your words, as the *sort* and *uniq* utilities both require input to be sorted in order to detect duplicates. If that's not what you want, I also posted a [Ruby solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35214259/1301972) that preserves the original word order.

## Rejoining Words

If, as one commenter pointed out, you're trying to reassemble your unique words back into a single line, you can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) to do this. For example:

```
$ echo $(echo -e "${variable// /\\n}" | sort -u)
alpha bravo charlie delta echo
```

The lack of quotes around the command substitution are intentional. If you quote it, the newlines will be preserved because Bash won't do [word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#index-word-splitting). Unquoted, the shell will return the results as a single line, however unintuitive that may seem.

Comment: @mklement0 I went with a different approach, since a here-string piped to sort and tr still spawns two processes. However, I think your here-string solution is interesting, and that you should post it as an answer. Thanks for your thoughtful comments!

Comment: Thanks, @CodeGnome. I'm recreating my earlier comment (part of which no longer applied) with my proposed alternative here (don't think it's worth posting as a separate answer): `sort -u <<<"${variable// /$'\n'}" | tr '\n' ' '`.
This spawns 2 processes, as you state. Your equivalent command (with the rejoined words) spawns 3 processes, and also makes the resulting words subject to pathname expansion (globbing).

Comment: This was new to me that bash substitution could handle newlines. Thanks for this. Having to use only one built-in adds to my bash proficiency and also since I may be using this a bit, saves a bit of time.

Answer (score 6):

You may use `xargs`:

```
echo "$variable" | xargs -n 1 | sort -u | xargs
```

Comment: While this is _simpler to write_, it is also _less efficient_ than the OP's own solution, because it invokes the `echo` utility (twice) for _each_ input word. An explanation of `xargs`'s behavior would be helpful.

Comment: echo is a builtin. this is probably really not much slower than the other anser

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Note: This solution assumes that all unique words should be output *in the order they're encountered in the input*. By contrast, the OP's own solution attempt outputs a *sorted* list of unique words.</sup>

A simple **Awk-only solution** (POSIX-compliant) that is **efficient** by avoiding a pipeline (which invariably involves subshells).

```
awk -v RS=' ' '{ if (!seen[$1]++) { printf "%s%s",sep,$1; sep=" " } }' <<<"$variable"

# The above prints without a trailing \n, as in the OP's own solution.
# To add a trailing newline, append  `END { print }` to the end 
# of the Awk script.
```

- Note how `$variable` is *double-quoted* to prevent it from accidental [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), notably pathname expansion (globbing), and how it is provided to Awk via a [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString) (`<<<`).
- `-v RS=' '` tells Awk to split the input into *records* by a single space.

  - Note that the *last* word will have the input line's trailing newline included, which is why we don't use `$0` - the entire record - but `$1`, the record's first field, which has the newline stripped due to Awk's default field-splitting behavior.
- `seen[$1]++` is a common Awk idiom that either creates an entry for `$1`, the input word, in associative array `seen`, if it doesn't exist yet, or increments its occurrence count.
- `!seen[$0]++` therefore only returns true for the *first* occurrence of a given word (where `seen[$0]` is implicitly zero/the empty string; the `++` is a *post*-increment, and therefore doesn't take effect until *after* the condition is evaluated)
- `{printf "%s%s",sep,$1; sep=" "}` prints the word at hand `$1`, preceded by separator `sep`, which is implicitly the *empty* string for the *first* word, but a single space for subsequent words, due to setting `sep` to `" "` immediately after.

---

Here's a more flexible variant that **handles any run of whitespace between input words**; it works with *GNU* Awk and *Mawk*<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{if (!seen[$0]++){printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=" "}}' <<<"$variable"
```

- `-v RS='[[:space:]]s+'` tells Awk to split the input into records by any mix of spaces, tabs, and newlines.

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, BSD/OSX Awk (in strict compliance with the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)), doesn't support using *regular expressions* or even multi-character literals as `RS`, the input record separator.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

### Preserve Input Order with a Ruby One-Liner

I posted a [Bash-specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35214172/1301972) already, but if you want to return only unique words while preserving the word order of the original string, then you can use the following Ruby one-liner:

```
$ echo "$variable" | ruby -ne 'puts $_.split.uniq'
alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
echo
```

This will split the input string on whitespace, and then return unique elements from the resulting array.

Unlike the *sort* or *uniq* utilities, Ruby doesn't need the words to be sorted to detect duplicates. This may be a better solution if you don't want your results to be sorted, although given your input sample it makes no practical difference for the posted example.

### Rejoining Words

If, as one commenter pointed out, you're then trying to reassemble the words back into a single line after deduplication, you can do that too. For that, we just append the [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) method:

```
$ echo "$variable" | ruby -ne 'puts $_.split.uniq.join(" ")'
alpha bravo charlie delta echo
```

Answer (score 1):

Using associative arrays in BASH 4+ you can simplify this:

```
variable="alpha bravo charlie alpha delta echo charlie"

# declare an associative array
declare -A unq

# read sentence into an indexed array
read -ra arr <<< "$variable"

# iterate each word and populate associative array with word as key
for w in "${arr[@]}"; do
   unq["$w"]=1
done

# print unique results
printf "%s\n" "${!unq[@]}"
delta
bravo
echo
alpha
charlie

## if you want results in same order as original string
for w in "${arr[@]}"; do
   [[ ${unq["$w"]} ]] && echo "$w" && unset unq["$w"]
done
alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
echo
```

Comment: Thanks that's a very good point. I've edited to take care of both. Please check last for loop to print results in original order.

Comment: Great answer still learning about arrays like this. A beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
$ echo "$variable" | awk  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (!seen[$i]++) printf $i" "}}'
alpha bravo charlie delta echo
```

If you do not want the trailing space and want a trailing CR, you can do:

```
$ echo "$variable" | awk  'BEGIN{j=""} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (!seen[$i]++)j=j==""?j=$i:j=j" "$i}} END{print j}' 
alpha bravo charlie delta echo
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

1. Pad the input string with a space before and after, `" $word_bag "` below,
2. Remove duplicates, `(\S+)` is `\2`, separated by whitespace, repeatedly,
3. Remove padding.

```
word_set=$(sed -E ':w s/(\s(\S+)\s.*)\2\s/\1/;tw; s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//' <<< " $word_bag ")
```

(Does not scale to very very long inputs.)

Answer (score -1):

pure, ugly bash:

```
for x in $vaviable; do 
    if [ "$(eval echo $(echo \$un__$x))" = "" ]; then
         echo -n $x
         eval un__$x=1
         __usv="$__usv un__$x"
    fi
done
unset $__usv
```

Comment: The use of subshells makes this inefficient, and the usual caveats re `eval` apply. Using `for` this way makes the words subject to pathname expansion. Here's a variant that addresses all these issues; `eval` is avoided by using variable indirection: `read -ra words <<<"$variable"; for w in "${words[@]}"; do vn="un_$w"; if [[ -z ${!vn} ]]; then echo -n "$w "; declare "$vn=1"; fi; done`